# Return a value from a method and re-use it to the next method inside class

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to understand classes and methods.

Let's say we have a custom class called `Nlkt_custom` with 3 methods allowing me to:

1. read a text file
2. tokenise the text
3. return word occurences

Is it a good practice to return `fic`, `words` and `sorted_freqs` and define them later on, in order to use their output to the next method? If not, what is the preferred way to construct these methods?

```
class Nltk_custom:
    _defaultEncoding = "utf-8"
    _defaultLang = "english"
    
    def __init__(self, filename, encoding=_defaultEncoding, lang=_defaultLang):
        self.filename = filename
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.lang = lang

    def custom_read(self):
        try:
            with open(self.filename, mode='r', encoding=self.encoding) as f:
                fic = f.read()
                return fic
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"File '{self.filename}' not found.")
        return None

    def custom_tokenisation(self, fic):
        words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(fic.lower(), self.lang)
        return words
    
    def sort_frequences(self, dictionnaire):
        # I am using it again in other methods, so I decided to create a function apart
        return dict(sorted(dictionnaire.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
    
    def custom_frq(self, words):
        freqs = FreqDist(words)
        sorted_freqs = self.sort_frequences(freqs)
        return sorted_freqs


fic_inst = Nltk_custom(filename="arandomfile.txt")
fic = fic_inst.custom_read()
words = fic_inst.custom_tokenisation(fic)

#words = Nltk_custom.custom_tokenisation(fic)

sorted_freqs = fic_inst.custom_frq(words)
```

Comment: Yes, you can use results from one method and pass them into another. However, Your last two lines aren't doing quite what you think they are. This will cause trouble if your `Nltk_custom` class resides in a different module.

Comment: @quamrana is it a good practice though? Would it be preferable to call "independently" ```sorted_freqs = Nltk_custom.custom_frq(words)``` without relying on ```words``` ?

Comment: This probably shouldn't be a class. The file handling is a separate concern entirely, and the juggling of `words` between two methods is awkward. Write a _function_ that takes the file content, as a string, and returns the frequency dictionary.

Comment: @quamrana and by last two lines, you are referring to the definition of global variables + calling the methods in the end aka ```words = Nltk_custom.custom_tokenisation(fic) and sorted_freqs = Nltk_custom.custom_frq(words)``` or ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's an exercice proposed in a chapter for classes and methods... I would just do it with simple functions, but it should be done as a class according to the exercice..

Comment: Yes, see my answer. Yes, the call: `words = Nltk_custom.custom_tokenisation(fic)` seems to pass `fic` as a parameter. However python will have assigned `self=fic` inside the method. (You don't use `self` in those methods, so you never see the trouble it could cause).

Comment: It's not clear what's exercise and what's solution, but what you've shown doesn't make sense as a class. You're effectively having to maintain the state of the class _outside it_, by holding references to the return from each method then pass it to the next. But even if that was accessed via `self` instead of parameters you'd still have a strong time dependence between the methods (e.g. you can't call `custom_tokenisation` until after `custom_read`). I'd also question the file handling (`return None`?) and use of defaults (why is `_defaultEncoding` a class attribute but `"english"` inlined?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe The aim of the exercise is to create a class with the 3 methods described above. There is no solution proposed. Regarding refs, this is exactly my issue. I cannot ran ```custom_tokenisation``` independentl (namely without executing  ```custom_read``` before). And normally I should be able to use a specific method of a class without depending on x methods before it (?). ```english``` is now default. Regarding ```return None``` I added this step in order to be sure that a "valid" file is being processed.

Answer (score 1):

You should have written your last two methods differently, and called them with the appropriate parameters:

```py
class Nltk_custom:
    ...  # other methods elided

    def custom_tokenisation(self, fic):
        words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(fic.lower(), self.lang)
        return words

    def custom_frq(self, words):
        freqs = FreqDist(words)
        sorted_freqs = dict( sorted(freqs.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
        return sorted_freqs


fic_inst = Nltk_custom(filename="arandomfile.txt")
fic = fic_inst.custom_read()
words = fic_inst.custom_tokenisation(fic)
sorted_freqs = fic_inst.custom_frq(words)
```

Note how `fic` and `words` are now parameters of the last two methods.

Comment: Should be `self.lang` too, but that's the _only_ reference to instance state in either method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Good spot. I'll fix that. However, that means that the OP didn't ever try to run the code :-(

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use the instance correctly. Is it a good practice to use ```fic``` and ``words`` as a parameter for the last two methods ?

Comment: Yes, its a *much* better idea to pass the parameters into a method rather than relying on globals.

Comment: @quamrana I ran the code, but I have ommited some parts before+after. Misstyped sorry. By assigning ```self=fic``` what problem would that cause?

Comment: Later on you want something that is defined in `__init__()`, so you use: `self.xxx` to access it, only to find that `self=fic` and `fic` is a string read from the file.

Comment: @quamrana in other words they are the same object  ? I am not sure I understand correctly

Comment: No, your `fic_inst` is an instance of `Nltk_custom`. Every method that is called, python assigns `self=fic_inst`. However, as above, if python assigns `self=fic` and you access my hypothetical `xxx` attribute like this: `self.xxx`, then python will complain: `str object has no attribute xxx`. You can try it yourself if you use the `custom_tokenisation()` method in my code above, but use your original call: `Nltk_custom.custom_tokenisation(fic)`

Comment: @quamrana why would self turn into a string obj in that case? should I declare ```self.fic = None``` inside init to avoid it? (and by extension the rest of the vars ? e.g. words, sorted_freqs)

Comment: Did you try the code as I said? Don't fix things that aren't wrong. Use the code from my answer.

Comment: @quamrana yes. But the error is not the one expected e.g. TypeError: Nltk_custom.custom_tokenisation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fic' (I am updating the code in the main question)

Comment: No, don't update the question. This is not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @quamrana Sorry. I wanted to help by allowing you to do a copy paste and reproduce the same error I had.

Comment: We don't know what error you had because you didn't post it. The question has always been about design considerations.

Comment: @quamrana I had no error before. My question is exactly as you said about design considerations. I've tried to reproduce the error in the case of ```self=fic``` as you proposed and I updated my code with a commented line (the part you suggested to try) and posted the error here as a comment